# Azure Sphere and IoT Edge

Tags: azure-sphere

Is it possible to deploy IoT Edge(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/) modules on Azure Sphere? If so, is there a tutorial I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported yet. Please vote for that feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge/suggestions/35859580-document-how-to-connect-azure-sphere-device-as-dow